# Is one allowed to lie to *possibly* preserve peace?

Tags: halacha, sheker-false, emes-truth-honesty, masechet-yevamot

The Gemara in Yevamos (65a) proves from various sources that one may lie, or at least tell a half-truth, to preserve peace, [at least regarding the past](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53799/should-you-change-the-truth-for-peace). (See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22057/why-did-god-lie-about-sarah) for more on that Gemara.)

Now, in all the scenarios presented there, the parties involved knew, or at least though, there would be strife otherwise. Would one be permitted to do so if you're unsure how the other party would react if you told the truth?

Comment: may be [linked](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71142/9215)

Comment: This is a fascinating question as it straddles the border between 2 apparent conflicting ideas - 1) Torah's command to "DIstance yourself from a false word" (Devarim) and Pirkei Avot (forgot exactly place) to "Be as the disciples of Aharon ... seeking peace." My instinctive answer is that Aharon himself told half-truths (ref. to Avot DRav Nattan who explains the last adage.) about what 2 fighting friends said so that he could restore peace.

Comment: @DanF Rashi on the pesukim surrounding Aharon's death says he would tell the husband how his wife talked about how great he was and just didn't want to say anything to him, and vice versa to the wife.

Comment: @DonielF Right. What's not apparent is if Aharon was lying.